# arrival.js not detecting injected element

Tags: javascript

I am trying out the [arrival.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) library to detect when an element is injected into the body or is somehow available in the `DOM`. This is the code I am trying in JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("body").append("<p class = 'foo'>Yep</p>");
}, 5000);

$(function() {   
    $(document).arrive(".foo", function() {
        alert("hell Yeah");
    });    
});
```

Problem is, the element does get appended to the body after 5 seconds, but the alert never comes up. Any idea how to make it work as expected?

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yab9hwvf/).

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/master/minified/arrive.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: Yep, that was the cause. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `arrive.min.js` in resource and use this cdn link

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/arrive/2.4.1/arrive.min.js

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yab9hwvf/2/)

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks mate!